# OpenGL window glitches

Tags: graphics, opengl

When I launch any software based on OpenGL, it can glitch at a certain screen size. When this happens, the window begins to wrap around and the GUI becomes unusable.

Here is a a screenshot to illustrate what I'm talking about (Steam properties window):[image: properties window steam]

This is getting really annoying and if anyone knows a solution, help would be much appreciated.

The output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`:

> OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-2f55476 2015-11-19 wily-oibaf-ppa)

(I installed oibaf's drivers because they are more up-to-date for my system).

Comment: What's your GPU brand? (Intel / NVidia / AMD) Did you installed the proprietary driver? One more question: What's the kernel version? (you can perform `uname -a` on the terminal and paste here.)

Comment: GPU is Intel. I will check the kernel when I get home. I did install the proprietary driver. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the window glitch is because OpenGL is not able to clear the COLOR_BUFFER_BIT and DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT .

And your version of OpenGL is very old . Update to newest by updating your GPU driver.

Here is a link describing how to add and install drivers for intel using a ppa

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5452-IOSM-1474

If you have Nvidia drivers then follow the following youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkKkuzWlaGo

Also a similar askubuntu thread has the similar outdated OpenGl driver problem . Fortunately that is solved

[How do I upgrade OpenGL? Intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703761/how-do-i-upgrade-opengl-intel)

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks. Although I recently replaced my laptop. So I don't get that issue anymore. Still, thanks for supplying the information. I can hope that it will be really helpful for someone in the future.