# How do I upgrade OpenGL? Intel

Tags: intel, opengl

Solved: The Intel Core i3 380M Processor does not support a higher level of OpenGL.  Anything past 2.1 is not currently available.

intel-linux-graphics-installer did not work out of the box.  Any suggestions to add to the initial install would be helpful.

```
    OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
    OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
    OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.4
    OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
    OpenGL extensions:
    OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.0.4
    OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: 
            OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: if you are using 15.10, see here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1

Comment: Once installed it shows a driver, but it's Unknown: Unknown.

Comment: The odd thing is is that I have an Intel HD 3000 card and it shows Ironlake as my graphics.

Comment: I'm on 15.10, by the way.  Lubuntu 15.10.  I tried it on Ubuntu 15.10 and the same thing occured.  I wonder if perhaps my graphics processor simply isn't compatible?  I'm sure there's some kind of workaround, but I have to find it.

Comment: I also don't particularly like to use any sort of ppa.

Comment: you have intel graphics processor, correct?

Comment: ironlake is the generation name like sandybridge or ivybridge is for the older generations

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Didn't know that about Ironlake, Sandybridge, and Ivybridge.

Comment: Discovered this is not possible, as only certain graphics cards can handle certain version of OpenGL.  A hardware upgrade is neccessary to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no available drivers that will enable OpenGL 3.0 for your GPU hardware at this point in time and there quite likely never will be.

See here - http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMDQ

Answer (score 3):

The intel-linux-graphics-installer is not a ppa although it is similar. The intel-linux-graphics-installer installs through https and automatically updates and upgrades your graphics processor to the newest graphics stack available through the intel open source project which is not published by intel but is endorsed by intel.

The intel-linux-graphics-installer does add a repository and checks your system and then installs the needed packages which may be a mix of packages available through the ubuntu repos and other packages available through the 01.org repo. You should only have to run it one time.

All I know is that I use it on my Sandybridge Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz and here is what my version shows:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
```

Here's how to install it:

```
mkdir intel; cd intel
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/15.10/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.2.1-0intel2_amd64.deb
```

Here's how to run it:

```
sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

reboot

please post any errors

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Fifth_generation Which processor do you have i3?

Comment: @Cyndekai I don't think it is supposed to show up in the additional drivers tab anyhow. The additional drivers tab isn't really associated with the intel-linux-graphics-installer. After running the tool, it should show a report. That report will either show what was installed or it will show no packages were installed.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz

Comment: @Cyndekai well the i3 *should* be sandybridge (HM65 instead of 55) but maybe it's an early build?

Comment: @Cyndekai I don't know. Here is an i3 HM65 that shows intel hd graphics and not hd 3000. It has a different clock speed but it shows that it may not be hd 3000. HP shows the hd graphics and hd 3000 were both available for this model. It is always possible that it is not being detected properly as well but I know nothing about how to fix that as of now, although I'll check around.

Comment: @Cyndekai additionally, run this  instead and you may get more detail: glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL|version"

Comment: @Cyndekai also: sudo apt-get install i915-4.0.4-3.19-dkms

Comment: E: Unable to locate package i915-4.0.4-3.19-dkms
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'i915-4.0.4-3.19-dkms'

It must not be in my sources.

Comment: Edited original post to include more info.

Comment: @Cyndekai it's provided by the 01.org repo, you should have a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list

Comment: I did a clean install of Lubuntu, followed the directions you gave me, and still I'm at: 
        OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.2

Are there any other steps I should take to 'enable' the new drivers perhaps?

Comment: @cyndekai I wonder if this is a bug as I think your mobo and i3 are sandybridge instead of ironlake although I could be wrong.

Comment: That would be nice.  I'm not sure if it's Sandrybridge or Ironlake, though.  It seems as thought it 'should' be Sandybridge seeing as it is an i3.  In regards to Ironlake: it doesn't support OpenGL 3.0+.  http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMDQ

Comment: "Sandy Bridge (2nd gen Intel HD graphics 2000 3000)" Is mine perhaps 1st gen Intel HD 3000?

Comment: My hardware ended up not being supported.  Thank you for your help.  I wish I could select two answers.

Comment: @cyndekai yeah, that's what that wikipedia link I posted says but the HP docs for your model shows 2 types, Celeron and generic intel are one type that ship with intel he graphics on an hm55 and hd 3000 is also available and it looks like that is the I series on an hm65. I always assumed the integrated gpu was part of the mobo I guess it varies.