# Lubuntu 21.04 Artifacts in openGL

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, intel, opengl

I installed 64 bit lubuntu on a small tablet.

CPU/GPU: intel z3735f

RAM: 2GB

Everything works incredibly well, even web browsing :).

But 3d apps like some screen savers and games are showing these things:
[image]
(This is a game called revolt)
Lines appear only in distant objects, and I saw them in all kind of apps. OpenGL apps work well and fast, just like they did on windows (this tablet came with windows 8.1).

Is this a bug? or is it just that the intel graphics are not well supported?.

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/700814/opengl-window-glitches?rq=1 helps

Comment: Nothing changed, I checked opengl info: "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-eb6d990 2021-04-29 hirsute-oibaf-ppa)"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the glitch happens if I update the drivers, using the default ones everything runs perfect. But I have to reinstall ubuntu. Is there any way to revert to the default intel drivers?